# custom extension in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, word-2016

I'm trying to edit a `.lng`(Language) file in `notepad++`. My file contains two languages type. `LTR && RTL`. but I have a hard time for editing it. It is really messed up. but inside word I don't have any problem and everything is fine. Now the problem is I don't see any `.lng` extension in `Microsoft Word`.

Is there any workaround that I could export my file with this `.lng` or any other extension?